# Sum wont add decimal places (doubles)

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, sum

When I call this method it will only return the digits before the decimal place for instance:

```
1

2

3

= 6
```

This is fine but when I try:

```
1.5

2

3.5

= 6
```

How can I get it to sum the decimal places?

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]


    public string CalculateSum(List<int> listDouble)
    {
        return listDouble.Sum().ToString();


    }
}
```

}

If I use public string `CalculateSum(List<double> listDouble)` the result is always 0.

No matter what I type in.

This is how I am passing information:

```
        {
            CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
            CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt arrayOfInt = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt();
            arrayOfInt.AddRange(listDouble.Select(d => (int)d).ToList());

string result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);




                }
```

Comment: You have a `List<int>` as parameter. Shouldn't it be a `List<double>`?

Comment: You're passing in a List of Integers, how is it supposed to know what the decimal places are?

Comment: As I can see you used select not Sum

Comment: Using double returns 0 every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your parameters:

```
public string CalculateSum(List<int> listDouble)
```

That's a list of *integers*, despite the name. If you meant it to be a list of doubles, you should change the type:

```
public string CalculateSum(List<double> listDouble)
```

You'll need to uncomment your proper `Sum` implementation, too... returning the result of calling `ToString` on the return value from `Enumerable.Select` really isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to get the result I need? Btw using double returns for any number inputed 0! Int works its just wont add the decimals (obviously)

Comment: @Garrith: Without changing the input type? Of course not - once you've lost the data, how do you expect to get it back?

Comment: @Garritt: After changing the parameter type, did you update your calling code's generated proxy?

Comment: HAHA OMG! Jon Skeet you are a legend now I can change to array of double, arghh blasted visualstudio!

Answer (score 3):

Your method makes no sense. You're casting each item in a list of `int`s (integers - you know, *whole* values, hence the issue) to a `double`, which won't change the actual numerical value, and then taking the string representation of the list. That shouldn't even give you `6`. I think you meant:

```
public string CalculateSum(List<double> listDouble)
{
     return listDouble.Sum().ToString();
}
```

Comment: As ive said to the rest doing this will return 0 as an answer to the sum.

Comment: @Garrith: Why are you still casting everything to `int`? Just call `client.CalculateSum(listDouble)`. Also, why are you calling `Convert.ToString` on something that's already a string?

Comment: lmao one would think! Trust me I tryed that... you cant pass a double with arrayOfInt

Comment: And you cant pass it without calling the servicereference

Comment: Nicely spotted on the convert to string on the label my bad on that.

Comment: @Garrith: See Jon Skeet's comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a list of integers.  Integers cannot hold decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

your listDouble doesn't contains doubles! Its a List of integers!

```
public string CalculateSum(List<double> listDouble)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with that method.  It will cast the doubles to integers before adding them.

If you always have just one place after the decimal you could multiple each number by 10, get the sum, and divide the result by 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string CalculateSum(List<int> listDouble) 
{ 
    //return listDouble.Sum().ToString(); 

     return listDouble.Select(n => (double)n).ToString(); 

}
```

Data type issue

```
public string CalculateSum(List<int> listDouble)
```

Should be

```
public string CalculateSum(List<double> listDouble)
```

Comment: This returns a 0 using double

Answer (score 1):

When you use integers, your number is automatically parsed which drops decimal points. You need to use Double to represent your variable - then you'll be able to keep your decimals.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're summing integers instead of decimals try replacing

```
List<int>
```

to

```
List<decimal>
```

in your method signature